# redirect all static html files inside a certain directory to the root domain without extensions

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I need help optimizing my .htaccess to automaticall redirect all pages in a certain directory to the root domain without extension.

I've several pages inside the directory `www.example.com/p`, 
I need to redirect all pages like `www.example.com/p/about.html` to `www.example.com/about`.
Can this be done in a few lines in my htaccess without having to add every single page to htaccess

Thank you in advance

Comment: what have tried/searched? try "URL rewriting"

Comment: I've found codes like that `RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html?$ /$1 [L,NC,R=301]` but I don't know how to modify this code for my situation

Comment: Please edit your question to add basic grammar. A sentence begins with a capital character and ends with a full stop. There is a space behind a comma and a full stop. This gives me a headache trying to read it.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a simple 301 redirect code and finally I solved the problem using that code

```
RedirectMatch 301 /p(.*)\.html$ //$1
```

Comment: Extra points for realizing [you didn't actually need `mod_rewrite` to do this.](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/WhenNotToUseRewrite)

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the `.htaccess` file in your website's `/` root directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+p/(.*)\.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /p/$1.html [L]
```

This rewrites all pages like `www.example.com/p/about.html` as `www.example.com/about` and then resolves the content back again from the `/p` directory without the URL changing in the address bar.

Comment: Thank you Ravi but I'm actually migrating content I was struggling to find an answer here finally I created this code myself and it worked `RedirectMatch 301 /p(.*)\.html$ //$1`

Comment: Good to know you worked it out yourself but just out of curiosity how does your website resolve content for the URLs like `www.example.com/about`? Are these directories with `index.html` files inside?